# Spring pageable force add sorted value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, pageable

I want to force add sorting parameter to Pageable, even if one is passed. `@SortDefault(sort = {"id"})` works well, but only if sorting value is not passed. If is - this annotation is **ignored**.
How to add "*sort by id*" even if sorting by other fields is passed? The sorting by ID should be on last place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a little walkaround that works:

```
var pageableWithId = PageRequest.of(
        pageable.getPageNumber(),  
        pageable.getPageSize(),
        pageable.getSort().and(Sort.by("id")));
```